# What particular practices, designs, languages/features enable very easy to maintain code?

Tags: language-features, maintainability

What particular practices, designs, languages/features enable very easy to maintain code?

Comment: I guess that is the million dollar question, now isn't it.

Comment: **A.**  This should probably be community wiki, since there is no "one answer".  **B.** Read Code Complete (http://www.cc2e.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Descriptive Naming conventions and Loose Coupling get my votes.